# Join two querys

Tags: mysql

I have two query.

```
`SELECT 
total,from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_count_repo
where add_time >= CURDATE()`
```

and

```
`SELECT 
  order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method method,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method `
```

I try to join this

But something went wrong.  Every derived table must have its own alias error

Comment: What you really want to do?

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero result of first query is 5 rows, secon query is 3 rows. I want to get 8 rows finaly in one query

Comment: Using join require both queries have the same column count.Your first query has 4 columns and your second 3. This will not work.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate one result set to another, ordinarily it's best to use `UNION ALL`.

But, I suspect you're confused about how SQL works. It deals in rectangles of data. Each result set is such a rectangle. It has a certain number of columns, each showing a certain type of information.  And, each result set has a certain number of rows. Every row of a result set has columns of the same type as every other row.

The first result set in your question has four columns and the second one has three columns.  It makes very little sense to try to cram those into a single result set.

Answer (score 0):

try this(
Assuming that 'idCommon' is the id in common between both tables):

```
`SELECT 
total,from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_count_repo
INNER JOIN (
`SELECT 
  idCommon,
order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method method,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method `

) as t ON t.idCommon=delivery_count_repo.idCommon -- you must cross id's Common

where add_time >= CURDATE()`
```